# How to get the maximum number of all the rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I have a column like the one below which contains arrays and number.

I would like to know how to get the maximum number of all the rows i.e if there is only one number, then take the number.

For example, I will get `0.39` for the 1st row and `0.33` for the second...

```
print(df)

|    | unit_price                                |
|----|-------------------------------------------|
| 0  | 0.39                                      |
| 1  | [0.29, 0.3, 0.33]                         |
| 2  | [0.34, 0.35, 0.39]                        |
| 3  | 0.39                                      |
| 4  | 0.39                                      |
| ...| ...                                       |
| 444| [0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48]|
| 445| [0.47, 0.48]                              |
| 446| [0.47, 0.48]                              |
```

Comment: what data structure is that table?

Answer (score 1):

You can harness `numpy.max` function for this task following way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[0.39,[0.29,0.3,0.33],[0.34,0.35,0.39]]})
df['maxprice'] = df.price.apply(np.max)
print(df)
```

output:

```
                price  maxprice
0                0.39      0.39
1   [0.29, 0.3, 0.33]      0.33
2  [0.34, 0.35, 0.39]      0.39
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the type of the data is `list` then take the `max` else take the value (i.e. single number)

```py
df['unit_price'].apply(lambda x: max(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```